# Freeze columns/header in place in ASP GridView Chrome and IE9+

Tags: css, google-chrome, c#-4.0, internet-explorer-9, aspxgridview

I am trying to lock the first 2 columns and the header row of an ASPX DataGrid.  I have tried using CSS expressions ( I later found out they were deprecated) and various CSS hacks.  I have not seen anything that can seem to get what I am wanting.  I want this to behave kind of like Excel as far as freezing panes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this done, not quite the way in which I desired, but done nonetheless by utilising JQuery.

I used the code from http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/ .